# Reference Content Block Not Working

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template

During "Preview and Test" my Reference Block is not working.

It only shows `%%=ContentBlockbyID("12874")=%%`, inside this `ContentBlockID` is my Physical Mailing Address and Profile Center, since it is not showing in Preview And Test, i'm having an Error saying that my Physical mailing address and Profile center is missing.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: are you previewing using a subscriber? The content in Reference Block only fills in inside of a 'Send' environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jay-O Victoriano insert the Physical mailing address and Profile center in the Email template these are the required for all email template [image]

and in email tool: drop down take profile center also like Physical mailing address

Comment: the Physical Mailing Address and Profile Center was already part of the Email Template. That is the content of the Reference Block that is not working.

Comment: are you using template based email ?

Comment: @Jay-O Victoriano use like this %%=ContentAreaByName('my contents\foldername\contentname')=%%

Comment: @Jay-O Victoriano  save your content block in Conent Builder then try with %%=ContentBlockbyID("12874")=%%

Answer (score 0):

This is, I believe, is still a known issue - https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003USpQAM . You can circumvent this by logging a case with SF support and having them turn of the check for the Physical Address and Subscription Center. This is of course assuming you're utilizing a custom footer and HTML template.